# Linux: Non-Executable Installation File

Tags: linux, matlab, executable

I've gotten a USB drive in which the installation files of MATLAB are found. I've tried executing the following command but none worked. Something is wrong. The file doesn't seem executable.

This is the file I need to execute:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    8360 Jul 19 03:29 install
```

I do:

```
sudo sh ./install
```

and get:

```
./install: 1: exec: /media/user/DPI/R2019b/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied
```

I tried `chmod +x install` but it also doesn't work. The file cannot be turned into an executable one.

Is the file corrupt, or do I miss something?

Comment: Probably the USB drive is formatted as FAT32 or similar which does not support UNIX file permissions. Probably you lost the permissions information when you/someone copied the files to the USB drive. You can copy all contents from the USB drive to your system's hard disk and change the permissions as necessary. The difficulty is that you don't know the correct permissions. It would be better to create a `.tar` or `.tar.gz` of the original files on a Linux system, copy this archive to the USB drive and extract it on your target system.

Comment: I've tried to copy the files to a local folder, but it did not change anything, I still cannot execute that `install` file. Although now it does appear to be executable, at least.

Comment: Copying the files itself does not change anything, but allows you to manually modify the permissions, e.g. `chmod a+x install` should have an effect. Please [edit] your question and show the exact command and error message and if applicable the `ls -l` output for the affected file, e.g. `ls -l /some_directory/DPI/R2019b/bin/glnxa64/install_unix`.

Comment: @Bodo It was your first guess. The drive's format. Once I changed it to a Unix compatible format. the problem was gone. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the USB drive is formatted by the manufacturer as FAT32 or similar. This file system doesn't support UNIX permissions.

That means you lose the permission information when you copy the files to a USB drive.

You have several options to fix this:

1. On a Linux/UNIX system create a `.tar` archive of the files, copy the archive onto the USB drive and unpack the archive to a UNIX compatible file system on the destination system. (This is a bit more work but allows to use the USB drive also on a Windows system.)
2. Format the USB drive as a UNIX compatible file system. (This might be the best solution if you plan to use the USB drive with Linux systems only. You can no longer use it on a Windows system except if you install special drivers.)
3. Copy all the files from the USB drive to a local drive on the destination system, which schould have a UNIX compatible file system, and try to fix the permissions manually. (I don't recommend this solution except if you cannot use the others, e.g. if you no longer have access to the original files.)